# Are vector images useful for Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, vector, svg, android-imageview

I am developing Android application. I want to use vector image. `(.svg file)` But I am not confident best way is using vector image.

`Svg-android.jar` is not usefull. Not support all of .svg file types. It may be trouble later time. On the other hand, if I use vector, it is much easy for me. Especially I will not work on resolutions.

I need help. I must decide as soon as possible.

Any suggestions?

Comment: If you need vector images just for GUI consider using 9-patch images instead.

Comment: If you don't like SVG-Android (I would use it anyway), check this out: https://github.com/TrevorPage/TPSVG_Android_SVG_Library

Comment: I am trying your suggestion.

Comment: Use Surfaceview and canvas for vectorized pictures.

Answer (score 23):

Vector graphics are a bad good idea.

Android was not designed to use them. So if you go that route, you'll have to fight against the green robot every step of the way. And let me tell you that little robot devil as got a lot of stamina !!

When you start fresh on a new language don't try to outsmart it. You will always loose time, hair and sanity.

Android uses a 'quite complex to grasp' concept that mixes resolution and screen sizes and nine-patches. But once mastered it is not that far fetched and you'll realize that the reason they chose this pattern is simple : When dealing with such screens fragmentation there is really no other alternative.

Please read : 
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

And the closest thing to vector graphics in Android :  http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html (As advised by Dmitry Zaitsev)

Comment: 9-patches can't represent many things. For example, you can't draw an oval with 9-patch

Comment: That's right you can't. I never said you could. If you need complex shapes then you'll have to default to the screen size support mecanism and provide different graphics for different screen sizes.
You can also use shapes, if your design is not to complex. See : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape

Comment: +1 Good Advice, was about to start using vector images

Comment: [Vector Asset Studio](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/vector-asset-studio.html) is something that people might want to take a look at. [I know this is an old question but I wanted to add an answer for the sake of completeness].